# Curl. Защита от парсинга

Tags: curl, php, парсер

Здравствуйте!
Пишу парсер для определенного типа страниц. Но сервер не отдает страницу, видимо защиту опставили. Думал палят по `USERAGENT`, и установил параметр в "`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; I; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0`". Не помогло :(
Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, как это обойти?

Comment: Браузером эти страницы открывабтся? Если да, то попробуйте посылать в запросе в точности такие же хедеры, которые посылает браузер.

Comment: а ещё куки и refer'ы могут проверятся.